# In Ruby, what are local gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

What does it mean when Ruby refers to gems as being local? i.e.: when you type in the root of your app directory, `gem list`, the result is:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actioncable (5.0.1, 5.0.0.1, 5.0.0)
actionmailer (5.0.1, 5.0.0.1, 5.0.0)
...
```

What does this have to do with Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those would be gems installed on your computer. As opposed to the ones that are available from rubygems.org.

It's not specific to Rails, and can refer to any Ruby gem.

Comment: I thought that gems available installed on your computer are global. Just curious the difference between local and global gems?

Answer (score 1):

Gems in `gem list` can either be local gems, on your machine, or remote gems, on the remote server, typically `https://rubygems.org/`. So one way of thinking about the command is the list does not have remote gems.

Gems on your machine, and local is the default.

```
$ gem list --local


*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actioncable (6.1.4.1)
```

Remote gems is a much longer list found on the "remote" domain. The remote domain 'source' can be found in `gem env` or `gem sources` and commonly is `https://rubygems.org`.

```
$ gem list --remote 

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

- (1)
-A (0.0.0)
.cat (0.0.1)
.omghi (2)
01xinan-metasploit-framework (6.0.17)
0mq (0.5.3)
```

`gem list` can also list both see `gem list --help`